# Instaling magento from command line errors

Tags: php, apache, magento

I follow this guide.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

I tried to run web installatin but it always got stucked so now i try this.

when i go to mysql as root

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

there are not any tables for magento.

So i run this command given in the link

```
magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
```

but mine cant run `magento` so i use `./magento`

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento --admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'magento'@'localhost' (using password: YES)



  [InvalidArgumentException]   
  Parameter validation failed
```

and other green writings

> ```
> setup:install [--backend-frontname="..."] [--key="..."] [--session-save="..."] [--definition-format="..."] [--db-host="..."]
> ```
>
> [--db-name="..."] [--db-user="..."] [--db-engine="..."]
>   [--db-password="..."] [--db-prefix="..."] [--db-model="..."]
>   [--db-init-statements="..."] [-s|--skip-db-validation]
>   [--http-cache-hosts="..."] [--base-url="..."] [--language="..."]
>   [--timezone="..."] [--currency="..."] [--use-rewrites="..."]
>   [--use-secure="..."] [--base-url-secure="..."]
>   [--use-secure-admin="..."] [--admin-use-security-key="..."]
>   [--admin-user="..."] [--admin-password="..."] [--admin-email="..."]
>   [--admin-firstname="..."] [--admin-lastname="..."]
>   [--cleanup-database] [--sales-order-increment-prefix="..."]
>   [--use-sample-data] [--magento-init-params="..."]

it says in informaton

```
--db-user

User name of the Magento database instance owner.

Default is root.
```

so i use my mysql password and admin name for it. this time it works but another errors

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magentodb --db-user=root --db-password= root --admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US --currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --cleanup-database help



  [RuntimeException]   
  Too many arguments.
```

SO, i decrease paramters. but again same

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento/ --db-host=localhost --db-name=magentodb --db-user=root --db-password= root 



  [RuntimeException]   
  Too many arguments.
```

i can see

http://localhost/magento2/setup/#/landing-install

page here. i think there are no errors. i can run also setup but it stucks at %66 %67. yesterday icompleted this but it was not adding to shoopping card, today i deleted all php 5.6 7.0 in my pc and reinstalle all. BUt now, it cant install..

what can be reason? i downloaded magento from web and extracted to ww/html

directory is

```
/var/www/html/magento2/bin
```

even for this errors

```
root@vegan:/var/www/html/magento2/bin# ./magento setup:install admin-user="root"



  [RuntimeException]   
  Too many arguments.


by the way i create user and daabase before installation

    mysql -u root -p
    CREATE DATABASE magentodb;
    CREATE USER magento@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'magento';
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES on magentodb.* to magento@localhost;
    FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
    exit
    mysql bu
    11-  service apache2 restart
    12-  service mysql restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted all `php`, reinstalled `php5.6` and it worked.